# Content in SP 2010 Outlook OWA Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, exchange-server

I'm currently struggling with the 2010 Sharepoint Outlook (OWA) webparts. I can put them on my site, i get prompted to login (in OWA), but when i login i get this error.

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame.

I've read alot about the topic, but haven't found a answer to if it's possible to get it working or not.

We're currently running SharePoint 2010, and OWA 2013. Upgrading to SharePoint 2013 is in the pipeline, but not around the corner...

Outlook is running locally, but will be moved to the cloud (MS 365) and SharePoint is locally hosted.